# Passenger Under Mountain Lion Not Loading Anything

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, osx-mountain-lion

I upgraded to ML this morning, and it seemed to go fairly smoothly but everything to do with Passenger has died. I've stripped it back to ground zero and uninstalled everything but RVM, gone to 1.9.3 as recommended for ML compatibility and reinstalled Passenger with the net result of nothing.

As it stands setting up sites directly or with PassengerPrefPane ends up with the site not responding. There's nothing negative in the logs that I can see, my Rails setup is working with `rails s` and Apache is definitely running. Anyone got any pointers I can run with, I'm drawing a blank now.

EDIT: Got a bit further now. Passenger is definitely running with a vhost along these lines:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName nicholassmith.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/nicholas/Development/Websites/DWC/public
    <Directory /Users/nicholas/Development/Websites/DWC/public> 
            Allow from all
            Options -Multiviews
    </Directory>
    RailsEnv development
</VirtualHost>
```

Which is in my httpd.conf. However where it says ServerName? It ignores that completely, returns nothing. If I go to localhost however, I'm in business, so I'm completely puzzled at this stage.

Comment: Did you change the Passenger and Ruby version in the Apache2 configuration files? It should be somehow like http://www.fngtps.com/2008/using-passenger-on-osx-for-rails-development/

Comment: Went to a default apache2 configuration and started from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just got this fixed, so for anyone else having issues:

1) Dive into httpd.conf and look for httpd-vhosts.conf
2) Uncomment
3) Drop your vhost in

Restart apache. Done.

Answer (score 0):

When I installed Mountain Lion, it overwrote the httpd.conf I had with a new one; you'll need to re-add the Passenger Pane vhost section to the bottom. Mine looked something like:

```
<IfModule passenger_module>
  NameVirtualHost *:80
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName _default_
  </VirtualHost>
  Include /private/etc/apache2/passenger_pane_vhosts/*.conf
</IfModule>
```

This would go below the line:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf
```

Comment: Tried restoring my previous httpd.conf, tried an entirely brand new one from fresh, and I tried a manually added vhost. No dice on either one.

Comment: Is there anything strange in your error_log? And when you restarted Apache, did it complain about anything?

Comment: It throws references to CRL missing, but not not in the directories it's looking in for Rails, other static sites work and not when I'm accessing the sites local URLs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with whatever CRL is, so I'm not entirely sure what the problem could be, then. You ran `sudo passenger-install-apache2-module` and updated the passenger config itself when you updated, I assume?

Comment: Yeah, pulled it all out and retried and still nothing. Apache seems to be finding the passenger module fine, but not piping it through.

Answer (score 0):

Mountain Lion cleared out the LoadModule statements from my apache httpd.conf file.  By reinstating them from my backed up files, and then including my vhosts file, I was able to be up and away again:

```
/etc/apache2/extra/httpd.conf:

# my mods for passenger
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/lukeskywalker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/lukeskywalker/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /Users/lukeskywalker/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby
```

Uncomment the vhosts include statement further down the file:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

My relevant setup from the httpd-vhosts.conf file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName lightsaber.local
    DocumentRoot "/Rails/lightsaber/public"
    <Directory "/Rails/lightsaber/public">
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        RailsEnv development
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```